# Formatting LaTeX code with minted: makeatletter

Tags: minted

I am trying to set some LaTeX code with minted.

However, minted (or rather the lexer which it is using) assumes the @ character to be catcode other, as it usually is. In the code that I want to format, however, @ is always catcode letter. Therefore command names are highlighted incorrectly.

Is there an easy option to change that or would I need to write a custom lexer?
Does someone know a good tutorial on how to write a custom lexer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to hack myself into it.

With

```
$ find / -mount -name "*latex*" 2>/dev/null
```

I have found the location of pygments.

The file `lexers/_mapping.py` contains a line

```
'TexLexer': ('pygments.lexers.markup', 'TeX', ('tex', 'latex'), ('*.tex', '*.aux', '*.toc'), ('text/x-tex', 'text/x-latex')),
```

telling me that the lexer is contained in the file `pygments/lexers/markup.py` and that the class is called `TexLexer`.

I have copied the file to `lexer/latex_atletter.py` in the directory of my LaTeX project and removed all unneeded classes from it so that only the `TexLexer` class remains.

This class contains a line

```
(r'\\([a-zA-Z]+|.)', Keyword, 'command'),
```

I have added an `@` to the allowed letters in the regex (and a comment at the end of the line that I have edited it).

From [here](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/176) I have learned how to use this custom lexer in my LaTeX document:
I have added

```
\def\mylatexlexer{lexer/latex_atletter.py:TexLexer -x}
\newmintedfile[inputlatex]{\mylatexlexer}{}
```

to the preamble and replaced every occurence of `\inputminted{latex}` with `\inputlatex`.

Now, commands containing an @ symbol are highlighted correctly.